# Какая регулярка подойдет под эти символы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такой массив:

```
[''','"','.','!','@','#','№','$',';','%',':','^','&','?','*','(',')','-','_','+','=','{','}','[',']','\','|','/','`','~','<','>',' ']
```

Можно ли его переработать в регулярку чтоб под нее попадали все символы в любом месте строки кроме букв и цифр?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно всё, кроме букаф и цифр?
Проще не искать все НЕ буквы/цифры, а исключить онные.
Как-то так:

```
$str =~ /[^a-z0-9]*/i;
```

Answer (score 2):

Регулярка:

```
/(\W|_)/g
```

Пример кода:

```
var a = 'asdsda ;_-: dd'; 
console.log(a.match(/(\W|_)/g, ''));
```